# Unable to format a pen drive, volume does not contain a recognized system

Tags: filesystems, command-prompt, usb-drive

I want to format pendrive, but it shows the following message. Adding the screen shots of the same.

When i enter the command **format h :** following message is displayed.
[image]

I have entered the same command to format, then following message is displayed :

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
format /q /x H:
```

Assuming USB flash drive is H in your system. Replace if not.

Run Command Prompt as Administrator.